# ArrayList sent to server: Data retrieval

Tags: java, android, python, django, arraylist

In my android application I have an `ArrayList` which is: `[1, 2, 8]`

I am sending this array list in a job to the backed `django` view, where I need to process it further.

So I am calling the `toString()` method  to convert it to a string and then send it to the server.

Inside the view on getting the parameter from the request and on trying to print what I have received I get: `[1, 2, 8]`.

But on trying to get the 1st element, basically calling `varialble[0]` I am getting: `[` and on calling `variable[1]` I am getting `1`.

I just want to extract all the numbers from the variable and use them for further processing. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Look at the serialization. For example, on JSON format.

Comment: comma separated values in JSON? How do I do that?

Comment: `StringUtils.join(list, ",")` will result a string without `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert the arrayList values to a string, the '[' will also be treated as string in the convesrsion. U may use a JSON kind of object using javascript and append it to the request parameters. In django, we can use dictionaries to parse the JSON data as key-value pairs.